# problem on expand network using a router

Tags: home-networking

I have a Netgear FS605 v3 router, and i'm trying to expand my network. The router is connected to the cable modem with cat5 cable. I have 2 laptop connected to the router but i'm only able to get internet connectivity in one. The first laptop i turn on, get the signal and the other one will show no connectivity. I have restarted all the devices many times but no luck. Can somebody explain me how to get this solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the [Netgear FS605](http://www.netgear.com/Products/Switches/DesktopSwitches/FS605.aspx) is a [switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) not a [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router).  Your ISP probably only provides you with 1 IP address, and the first computer to connect to the network will get it.  You will need an actual router if you want to connect more than one computer without buying additional IP addresses from your ISP.

Here are a couple of questions that might help you in choosing a router:

- [Basic (cheap) wireless router recommendation for home](https://superuser.com/questions/66375/basic-cheap-wireless-router-recommendation-for-home)
- [Good reliable cheap router for dorm room?](https://superuser.com/questions/94095/good-reliable-cheap-router-for-dorm-room)

Comment: yep... right tool for the right job....  this being said... now that you already have a switch you do not need to worry about how many ports the router has.  you can connect toe router to the modem and the switch to the router to have more ports available and all will work great.  This said, for two laptops just about any router will do just fine without the need for your netgear switch.